# How to create a bar plot with a secondary grouped x-axis in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, charts, tidyverse

I'm looking to recreate the following bar chart using ggplot in R, but so far I've had no luck (please ignore the white line, I've had to blank out exact data):

[image]

I have my data arranged as follows, which I thought would be appropriate:

```
figure_1 <- tribble(
          ~"ResponseOption", ~"StimuliFormat", ~"rfg", ~"emmean", ~"SE",
          "RF_Ratings", "Picture", "Recollection", 2, 0.03,
          "RFBG", "Picture", "Recollection", 1, 0.03,
          "RFG", "Picture", "Recollection", 7, 0.03,
          "RF_Ratings", "Word", "Recollection", 04, 0.03,
          "RFBG", "Word", "Recollection", 3, 0.03,
          "RFG", "Word", "Recollection", 5, 0.03,
          "RF_Ratings", "Picture", "Familiarity", 2, 0.03,
          "RFBG", "Picture", "Familiarity", 1, 0.03,
          "RFG", "Picture", "Familiarity", 7, 0.03,
          "RF_Ratings", "Word", "Familiarity", 04, 0.03,
          "RFBG", "Word", "Familiarity", 3, 0.03,
          "RFG", "Word", "Familiarity", 5, 0.03,
          "RF_Ratings", "Picture", "Guessing", 2, 0.03,
          "RFBG", "Picture", "Guessing", 1, 0.03,
          "RFG", "Picture", "Guessing", 7, 0.03,
          "RF_Ratings", "Word", "Guessing", 04, 0.03,
          "RFBG", "Word", "Guessing", 3, 0.03,
          "RFG", "Word", "Guessing", 5, 0.03)
```

but I'm at a loss of how to have 2 grouping variables on the x-axis (Words/Pictures + RFG/RFBG/RFRatings). I could do 3 x separate bar charts and somehow (?) join them together, but I was looking for a more elegant solution, where I could input the two x-axis grouping variables into ggplot.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `facet_wrap` you can eventually get a similar plot by passing the facet labels on the bottom using `strip.position` argument and adding them outside of the plot area using `strip.placement = "outside"`:

```r
ggplot(figure_1, aes(x = StimuliFormat, y = emmean, fill = rfg))+
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = emmean-SE, ymax = emmean+SE), width  =0.2, position = position_dodge(0.9))+
  facet_wrap(~ResponseOption, strip.position = "bottom")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(strip.placement = "outside")+
  labs(x = "", y = "Proportion of hits")
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: Amazing, this is exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks!