# Nesting one factor within another in ggplot figures

Tags: ggplot2, nested, boxplot, axis, levels

I have two factors in my dataset (LocationTreatment[WebbHardRelease, WebbSoftRelease, SRSHardRelease, and SRSSoftRelease] and Location [Webb, SRS]) that I want to display simultaneously. I would like to display my response variables with these two factors nested within each other on the y-axis.

Here is what my figure currently looks like:
[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

Here is the line of code I am currently using to make one of the figures. I can change the other three if I know how to make this one display what I need:

```
FirstDayDistPlot <- SoftReleaseData %>%
  ggplot(aes(LocationTreatment, FirstDayDist))+
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar', width=0.2)+
  geom_boxplot(color="black", fill="grey", width = 0.3)+
  theme_bw()+  
  theme(text=element_text(family="Helvetica", size=12))+
  theme(axis.line.x.bottom = element_line(color="black"))+
  theme(axis.line.y.left = element_line(color="black"))+
  theme(axis.line.x.top = element_line(color="black"))+
  theme(axis.line.y.right = element_line(color="black"))+
  theme(axis.text.x.bottom = element_text(color="black",size=12))+
  theme(axis.text.y.left = element_text(color="black",size=12))+
  theme(axis.title.x.bottom = element_text(color="black",size=14))+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,700,100))+
  coord_flip()+
  annotate("text", x=4.4, y=40, label = "(a)", col="black", size = 8, fontface = 1, family = "Helvetica")

FirstDayDistFinal <- FirstDayDistPlot+labs(x=element_blank(), y = "First Day Displacement (m)")
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

I have looked into forums on the facet_wrap() command, but I can't quite find any examples like mine where I do not want to display a legend, but rather just have the axes tell the whole story for a more condensed figure.

Comment: would something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61002029/how-to-create-a-bar-plot-with-a-secondary-grouped-x-axis-in-r) be of assistance?

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I tried that facet_wrap approach but I was still having trouble because it was separating my graph into two panels. 

As I was trying to figure out how to keep it all one panel, I realized I could just add a y-axis title and then add a label with SRS and Webb using the labs function then add spaces between the words in order to center the locations over the hard and soft release axis marks. 

That should work for what I need. Thanks Mark.